# Which php `fetch_array` way should i use

Tags: php, mysqli

I was coding, while watching a Tutorial and i tried to figure why was this guy using `while($row = $result->fetch_array())` but i was always using `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` and i want to know if it matter or which way was right or wrong way?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using either one unless you know absolutely sure that `mysqlnd` will exist on the server your code will be run from. As using either requires a `mysqli_result` object. Which comes from `mysqli_query` (which you should not use), or a prepared statement and using `mysqli_stmt_get_result` (requires mysqlnd).

Comment: I don't know but I'v seen this and didn't understand

Comment: Don't use either one. Use foreach loop instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually `$result->fetch_array())` and `mysqli_fetch_array($result))` both do the same thing. But using `$result->fetch_array())` is object oriented style and `mysqli_fetch_array($result))` is traditional procedural style.

Also `mysqli_fetch_array()` will collect the data from database as an array.

You can use any one of them. But I prefer object oriented style.